# Rearrange to get $x$ and $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to rearrange this to get $x$ in terms of $y$, and also vice versa. I know some basic rearranging, but I'm struggling with the $xy$ term!

$$21x^2 + 14xy + 3y^2 -94x -30y + 107=0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the quadratic formula. Treat $y$ as an independent, and rearrange terms to get the following representation:
$$
21x^2 + x(14y-94) + (3y^2 - 30y+107) = 0
$$
Now, use the quadratic formula: given $ax^2+bx+c=0$, the formula for $x$ is:
$$
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$
Hence, applying it in this case, and applying routine simplifications, we get:
$$
x = \frac{47-7y \pm \sqrt{-(14y^2+28y+38)}}{21}
$$

This is $x$ in terms of $y$. The same can be done for $y$, treating $x$ as a constant, and we can see that:
$$
y = \frac{15-7x \pm \sqrt{72x-96-14x^2}}{3}
$$
Hope this helps. Of course, it is possible that the term within the square root becomes negative as $x$ or $y$ varies, in which case $y$ or $x$ respectively would become a (non-real) complex number .

Answer (score 0):

Hint: treat the relation as a quadratic equation of $x$ and $y$ as a constant when you want the relation of $y$ in terms of $x$ and vice versa.